# SE16n table edit works in DEV, but not in QA system

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I created a custom table. Editing works in a SAP dev system via se16n. But editing does not work in a quality assurance system.

Is there a way to edit the table anyway?

Comment: How do you edit the table in SE16N in dev system? Have you created a maintenance view for the table or set up the table as "Display/Maintenance Allowed" (SE11 Delivery and Maintenance tabstrip).

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai I set "Display/Maintenance Allowed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usally enter &SAP_EDIT when I am in TCODE se16n and then it is possible to edit the data directly on the database.

Comment: SAP has blocked `&SAP_EDIT`, cf the [SAP note 1420281 - CO-OM tools: SE16N: Deactivating &SAP_EDIT](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1420281/E)

Answer (score 6):

There is a trick if you have debugging authorisations.
Basically you go into SE16n and enter debug mode with /h. There you have to change two variables (GD-SAPEDIT and GD-EDIT) to "X" and voilà, you can now unleash chaos on the database.

For a detailed How-To click [here](https://sapyard.com/how-to-enable-table-entries-maintenance-in-se16n-alternative-for-sap_edit-and-uase16n/)

I should mention that this should not be done on a regular basis, because you can really mess up some stuff. (been there, done that)

Answer (score 5):

I usually use function module `SE16N_INTERFACE` for that:

[image]

You can use the tables parameters `IT_SELFIELDS` to filter.

Comment: Its great if you access to execute SE16N_INTERFACE in QA system but we do not have access in QC system to test function module / interface.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `SE11` T-code, enter a custom table and go to Menu, Utilities --> Table maintenance generation, there you can configure and generate an application to maintain the table.

When you're done with the Table maintenance generation, then you can maintain the custom table using `SM30` transaction if you have necessary authorization in QA environment. -**AmNoOne**

---

Comment: SAP has blocked editing via SE16n for a very good reason - it is a massive security hole.  This is the correct way to edit a custom table.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way. Unfortunately the question was different. It did not ask for the correct way (via sm30) but how to do cheating (like &SAP_EDIT).